# TypeError : expected 1D vector for x, I am getting scatter plot but I am not getting the respective trend line

Tags: python

Below is my code is written but I am getting the above-mentioned error. Can someone please help me in this regard? Thank you in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
csv = pd.read_excel("Slider.xlsx",sheet_name="K",skiprows=2,usecols = "E");
data = pd.read_excel("Slider.xlsx",sheet_name="K",skiprows=2,usecols = "F");
x = csv
y = data
plt.scatter(x, y)
z = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
p = np.poly1d(z)
plt.plot(x,p(x),"r--")
plt.show()
```

Comment: It looks like your `csv` is a dataframe instead of a series. Try printing it first to see if there is accidentally another column. If not, try using `pd.Series` instead.

Comment: I am a Mechanical Engineer, and I am new to this package, can you please elaborate on what I need to do.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it should be a simple `x.squeeze()`. Can't tell for certain without seeing what `x` is. Essentially, a dataframe is many columns (each column is called a series). When creating a scatter plot, you can only have a 1-dimensional array for x, and 1 dimensional array for y. That's why you need to convert it.